# A basic question based on the definition of limit point, closed set etc.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $E$ be a subset of it. Now, for any neighbourhood of $p$ there exists a point $q, q \neq p$ and $q$ is a limit point of $E$. Then I have to prove that $p \in E$. How to proceed ?

Actually, I have to prove the following :

If $X$ be a metric space and $E$ is a subset of $X$. Then I have to prove that closure(E) is a closed set i.e. if $p$ be a limit point of closure(E) then $p$ is a limit point of $E$ or $p \in E$.

Now, as $p$ is a limit point of closure(E) that means for any neighbourhood of $p$ there exists a point $q, q \neq p$ and $q \in E$ or $q$ is a limit point of $E$. If $q \in E$ then $p$ becomes a limit of $E$. Now if $q$ is a limit point of  $E$ I should be able to prove that $p \in E$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Do you mean $p\in \overline{E}$?

Comment: What does the neighborhood have to do with it?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Plz see my elaborated problem definition.

Comment: You could just prove that $\overline{E}^c$ is open.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan: I don't want to prove like that. I want to do so in a straight forward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the problem : You want to show that $\overline{E}$ is a closed set. Your approach is fine, except your conclusion that $p\in E$ is wrong.

What you want to do (if you want to follow this line of argument) is as follows : Let $p \in \overline{\overline{E}}$. Then, for any neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, there is a point $q\in \overline{E}$, such that $q \in U$. Since $q \in U$, and $q \in \overline{E}$, there is a point $r \in E$ such that $r \in U$.

Hence, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, $U\cap E \neq \emptyset$. Hence, $p \in \overline{E}$. You have thus shown that
$$
\overline{\overline{E}} \subset \overline{E}
$$
Since the other containment is trivial, your result follows.

Comment: In summary, if $p$ is a limit point of $\overline{E}$ then actually $p$ is a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ , $E = (-1,1)$ and $p = 1$.